# dealing with NULL values in where statement (SQL)

Tags: sql, null, where-clause

So I have query with the following where statement. Basically, I want to ensure there was no sports or player activity within the last 7 days.

```
WHERE......   
AND (( (SELECT max(sportswagerbyleague.asOfDate) 
            FROM sportswagerbyleague 
            WHERE sportswagerbyleague.userID = customer_profile.userID)  
                <= date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY  ) 
                AND ((SELECT max(pa.txndate) 
                    FROM player_activity pa 
                    WHERE pa.userID = customer_profile.userID) <= date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )
```

However, if there is a NULL value (aka that user either has no player activity or sports activity), then the WHERE statement becomes false for that particular user. I want the WHERE statement to remain true even for a single NULL value.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a value against a NULL value is always false, so you have to handle that case separately. You could use something like [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `NOT EXISTS` instead to avoid three-valued-logic:

```
WHERE......   
AND NOT EXISTS
 ( SELECT *
   FROM sportswagerbyleague 
   WHERE sportswagerbyleague.userID = customer_profile.userID  
     AND sportswagerbyleague.asOfDate > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
 ) 
AND NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT *max(pa.txndate) 
   FROM player_activity pa 
   WHERE pa.userID = customer_profile.userID
     AND pa.txndate > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
 )
```

Comment: any reason why it is " * " instead of "max(sportswagerbyleague.asOfDate) " or is it just a typo?

Comment: No type, aggregation like `max(sportswagerbyleague.asOfDate)` will always return a row (`NULL` if there's no matching row) , so `NOT EXISTS` will never be true.  `[NOT] EXISTS` is the only place where `*` is actually recommended :-)